# print the full line of the file if a string matched from another file in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, awk

### File1 id.txt

```
101
102
103
```

### File2 emp_details.txt

```
101 john USA
103 Alex USA
104 Nike UK
105 phil UK
```

if the id of a.txt match with the first column of emp_details.txt then out put with full line to a new file matched.txt.If not matched then out put with only id to a new file notmatched.txt

example:

### matched.txt

```
101 john USA
103 Alex USA
```

### unmatched.txt (assumed by the editor)

```
102
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? People here are generally very helpful, but we will not write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

**One-liner:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ arr[$1]; next }($1 in arr){ print >"matched.txt"; delete arr[$1] }END{for(i in arr)print i >"unmatched.txt"}' file1 file2
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk '
        FNR==NR{ 
                 arr[$1]; 
                 next 
        }
        ($1 in arr){ 
               print >"matched.txt"; 
               delete arr[$1]
        }
        END{
               for(i in arr)
                  print i >"unmatched.txt"
        }
    ' file1 file2
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat file1
101
102
103

$ cat file2
101 john USA
103 Alex USA
104 Nike UK
105 phil UK

$ awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1];next }($1 in arr){print >"matched.txt";delete arr[$1]}END{for(i in arr)print i >"unmatched.txt"}' file1 file2

$ cat matched.txt 
101 john USA
103 Alex USA

$ cat unmatched.txt 
102
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -f f1 f2 > matched  
grep -vf <(awk '{print $1}' matched) f1 > not_matched
```

**Explanation:**
use `file1` as pattern to search in `file2` and store matched results in `matched` file
use `matched` file's column1 as pattern to search in `file1` and store non-matches in `not_matched` file
`-v` means "invert the match" in grep

**Output** :

```
$ cat matched
101 john USA
103 Alex USA

$ cat not_matched
102
```

Comment: Or  `<(cut -d ' ' -f 1 matched)` instead of `awk`

Comment: Yeah or even `cut`, whatever OP prefers.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we expect you to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck. We usually don't provide complete answers on this site. As it's just a few lines lines, I hacked up a not very efficient version. Simply  loop over the id file and use egrep to find the matched and unmatched lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do
  egrep "^$p" emp_details.txt >> matched.txt
done <id.txt

while read p; do
  if ! egrep -q "^$p" emp_details.txt; then
    echo $p >> unmatched.txt;
  fi
done <id.txt
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). There's just no reason to ever write that code.

Answer (score 0):

It's an another thought compared to @Akshay Hegde's answer. Set the map for `$1` and `$0` in emp_details.txt into array `a`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} {if($1 in a){print a[$1]>>"matched.txt"}else{print $1 >> "unmatched.txt"}}' emp_details.txt id.txt
```